# Using the django syndication module with mongoengine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, rss, mongoengine

I am trying to build a custom generated RSS feed using django's built in Syndication Framework. I am using mongoengine to interface django with mongoDB.

I am storing a set of documents that have a list of tags attached to each document. It is modeled as the following:

```
 class Request(Document):
     ...
     tags = ListField(StringField())
     ...
```

Ideally what I'd like to do is to have users type in a series of tags and get an rss feed for a list of recent documents with that tag. Ex. `.../subscribe/One/Two` would pull up a feed with tags of "One" and "Two".

I've mapped my urls.py file to match this:

```
url(r'^subscribe/(?P<pattern>.+)', KeywordsFeed(), name='subscribe')
```

But I keep getting an error saying that

> settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Since I'm using mongoengine, my settings file looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy', 
    }
}
MONGODB_NAME = 'mydb'
mongoengine.connect(MONGODB_NAME)
```

Here is feeds.py:

```
class KeywordsFeed(Feed):
    title = "Data Request Repository"
    link = "/"
    description = "Description"

    def get_object(self, request, pattern):
        patternlist = string.split(pattern, r'/')
        pdb.set_trace()
        resultList = Request.objects(tags__in=patternlist)
        if len(resultList<1):
            raise ObjectDoesNotExist
        return 

    def title(self, obj):
        return obj.title

    def description(self,obj):
        return obj.description

    def items(self, obj):
        return obj
```

My thinking is that the syndication framework is doing some backend validation before serving the feed. I could also be understanding this framework wrong. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to connect to [real DB](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/guide/connecting.html#connecting-to-mongodb)?

Comment: @PuffinGDI mongoDB is running on localhost on the default port. I can do all sorts of queries on it using views, or the shell.

Comment: Try my answer. I hope it helps you :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe it's lost more configure to connect DB.

Give IP, username and password for connection.

Example:

```
from mongoengine import register_connection

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
    }
}

LOCAL_DBS = {
    'default':{
        'NAME': 'your_db_name',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '',
        'USER': 'user_name',
        'PASSWORD': 'password'
    },
}

MY_DB = LOCAL_DBS['default']
register_connection('default', MY_DB['NAME'], host=MY_DB['HOST'],
                    username=MY_DB['USER'], password=MY_DB['PASSWORD'])
```